# Extracting a string in csh

Tags: linux, string, shell, csh

Would you please explain why the following shell command wouldn't work:

```
sh-3.1$ echo $MYPATH
/opt/Application/DATA/CROM/my_application
sh-3.1$ awk '{print substr($MYPATH,3)}'
```

Thanks
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MYPATH` is not going to be substituted by the shell since the string uses single quotes.  Consider the following:

```
csh$ echo '{print substr($USER,3)}'
{print substr($USER,3)}
csh$ echo "{print substr($USER,3)}"
{print substr(dshawley,3)}
```

The usage of *single* quotes instructs the shell to pass the string argument to the program as-is.  *Double* quotes tell the shell to perform variable expansion on the argument before passing it to the program.  This is a basic shell feature that is common amongst shells and some programming languages (e.g., perl).

The next problem that you are going to run into is that `awk` will want quotes around the first parameter to `substr` or the parse will fail.  You will probably see an "Illegal variable name" warning in this case.  This is where I get lost with `csh` since I have no clue how to properly escape a double-quote within a quoted string.  In bash/sh/ksh, you would do the following:

```
sh$ awk "{print substr(\"$USER\",3)}"
input
^D
hawley
sh$
```

Just in case you do not already know this, `awk` will require an input stream before it is going to do anything.  I had to type "input" and the EOF character for the little example.

Answer (score 1):

[Quoting and escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell#Quoting_and_escaping)

```
"string" is a weak quote. Enclosed whitespace and wildcards are taken as literals, but variable and command substitutions are still performed.
'string' is a strong quote. The entire enclosed string is taken as a literal.
```

You can use the `-v` option to pass variable to `awk`:

```
awk -v mypath=$MYPATH 'BEGIN{print substr(mypath, 3)}'
```

Comment: BTW - this is actually a much better option than the one that I presented since it avoids the shell quoting headache completely =)